# Bash - sed multiple commands in single line

Tags: bash, sed

Playing with sed - the commands below do what's required but one liners would be better. I have tried combining the first two commands (with a separating ';') to remove the trailing ':' without success. Otherwise, resorted to removing the last ':' and writing to a new file to perform the next operation.

File 'sys' with a single line containing a variable number characters and ':' separator. For example;

Input - 'sys' first line `3.000000:50:` desired output, two variables `thd=3 mem=50`

```
thd=$(echo | sed 's/.......:.*//' < sys)
sed 's/:$//' < sys > sys1
mem=$(echo | sed 's|........:||' < sys1)
```

Is there a way to combine the first two sed commands to avoid writing a second file? I have tried this various ways

Something like this - EDIT: this is the wrong order to remove the trailing ':'

```
thd=$(echo | sed 's/:$//;s/.......:.*//' < sys)
mem=$(echo | sed 's|........:||' < sys1)
```

Output `3 50:` with the separator attached.

EDIT: This is the correct order and produces the desired output. Bash does not save the result of the first operation in the file sys. Which I should have picked up in the 3 liner.

```
thd=$(echo | sed 's/.......:.*//' < sys)
mem=$(echo | sed 's|........:||;s/:$//' < sys)
```

Comment: kindly include the input and complete desired output

Comment: I have modified the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two variables to be assigned values independently, the first containing the number before the point and the second the number between the colons, you can use an approach like

```
thd=$(cut -f1 -d. < sys)
mem=$(cut -f2 -d: < sys)
```

Assigning both at the same time is also possible:

```
read thd mem < <(tr "." ":" < sys | cut -f1,3 -d: --output-delimiter=" ")
```

Comment: The cut version is ideal. Just a few characters.

Comment: the read version requires the `tr -d` option. Still couldn't get it to work on my system.

Comment: If you use the `-d` option of `tr`, you will delete the separators and lose the information needed for proper field separation.

Comment: As you say `-d` doesn't work - this does `read thd mem < <(cut -f1,2 -d: --output-delimiter=" " < sys)` if happy to accept the trailing `.000000`, which makes no difference in my application - no need for the `tr` options in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ echo '3.000000:50:' | { IFS='.:' read thd x mem; echo "'$thd' '$mem'"; }
'3' '50'
```

Or this:

```
$ sys='3.000000:50:'; IFS='.:' read thd x mem <<< "$sys"; echo "'$thd' '$mem'"
'3' '50'
```

The above sets the "dont care" variable `x`. If you do not like that, you can assign `mem` twice.

```
$ sys='3.000000:50:'; IFS='.:' read thd mem mem <<< "$sys"; echo "'$thd' '$mem'"
'3' '50'
```

Comment: To read the file `sys` something like this `$ { IFS='.:' read thd x mem; echo "'$thd' '$mem'"; } < sys` Which I found more difficult with multiple fields to read.

Comment: The advantage of `read` is, that it does not require two sub shells and two `cut` calls.

Comment: I have played around with this one '{ IFS='.:' read thd x mem x img x cal; echo "'$thd' '$mem' '$img' '$cal' "; } < sys' how does the don't care variable work?

Comment: Should be `{ IFS='.:' read thd x mem x img x cal; echo "'$thd' '$mem' '$img' '$cal' "; } < sys` how does the don't care variable work?

Comment: When you split with `IFS='.:'`, you get three tokens: 3,  000000 and 50. Each token gets stored in one variable: `thd=3`, `x=000000` and `mem=50`. You have to store the zeros somewhere, although you do not need them. You can also do `unset x` after the `read`. Or you can assign `mem` twice. First with the zeros and then with the 50.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. This  `echo 3.000000:50:raw:TRUE: > sys`   `{ IFS='.:' read thd x mem img cal; echo "'$thd' '$mem' '$img' '$cal'"; } < sys` returns `'3' '50' 'raw' 'TRUE'` awesome!

Comment: And this - `echo 3.000000:50:raw:TRUE:4.000000 > sys` `{ IFS='.:' read thd x mem img cal cor x ; echo "'$thd' '$mem' '$img' '$cal' '$cor' "; } < sys returns '3' '50' 'raw' 'TRUE' '4'`